# Terminal can't find and run files in /home paths with variables $HOME or ~ when started by Desktop Entry file

Tags: python, linux, installation

### The situation

I am writing a python program for other people, which installs itself on user's machine. Installation works fine. But after installation, clicking on the software icon in window manager doesn't run the software. 
Upon closer investigation, I found out there is something wrong with HOME variable in DesktopEntry file.

### The question

I expect clicking on icon of this software should run it, but it doesn't. What is wrong? 
Found a duplicate question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080096/installed-desktop-file-to-have-users-home-directory-path-inserted) but still no answer.

### Info

This is the technical part of `.desktop` file you may need to know about, omitting `Exec` and `Icon` lines:

```
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=true
X-SingleMainWindow=true
```

#### Trial and error of `Exec` and `Icon`:

Each block pair below shows a modified `.desktop` part and corresponding terminal output.

**Attempt 1**

```
Exec=python $HOME/.local/share/myProject/main.py
Icon=$HOME/.local/share/myProject/icon.svg
```

```
python: can't open file '/home/user0/$HOME/.local/share/myProject/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**Attempt 2**

```
Exec=python ~/.local/share/myProject/main.py
Icon=~/.local/share/myProject/icon.svg
```

```
python3: can't open file '/home/user0/~/.local/share/myProject/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**Attempt 3**

```
Exec=python $USER/.local/share/myProject/main.py
Icon=$USER/.local/share/myProject/icon.svg
```

```
python: can't open file '/home/user0/$USER/.local/share/myProject/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If command of Exec entered in Terminal, error message shows two usernames in its path like `/home/user0/user0/.local`...

**Attempt 4** 
Omitting the "extra" part...

```
Exec=python /.local/share/myProject/main.py
Icon=/.local/share/myProject/icon.svg
```

obviously doesn't and shouldn't work, as expected.

```
python: can't open file '/.local/share/myProject/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

### Notes

- When the command from `Exec` in first two attempts is called from terminal directly, python runs the script normally. But I don't want to make the user open terminal. Clicking on app icon should start it immediately.
- In none of above attempts, was the icon shown (only Name). So I finally moved it to `~/.local/share/icons` and written its name in place of path. This solved the issue for icon. Now I see both name and icon of my App but it still doesn't run.
- Command `desktop-file-validate` in terminal returns nothing for `.desktop` file.

Comment: error shows `/home/user0/$HOME/.local/` - so it looks like it automatically add `/home/user0` and maybe you should skip `$HOME`  and use only `Exec=python .local/share/myProject/main.py` without `$HOME`, without `$USER`, without `~`, without `/` at the beginning

Comment: Damn, this actually worked @furas and the problem is solved thank to your contribution. Anyways I'm still curious what caused the issue; `$HOME` is not supposed to make that kind of output. If you or anyone else reading this knows more and cares to tell, I'd be happy to learn more.

Comment: `$HOME`, `$USER` and `~` are replaced by `Bash` but it may run it directly in Linux without running `Bash`.

Comment: if you need full path then I would rather use `f-string` or `string formatting` in Python to generate all data and later save in file `.desktop`.